# NameError with non-existing class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dependencies

I hope someone here can help me. I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Subscription::SubscriptionContactDatum
```

The problem is that `SubscriptionContactDatum` doesn't exist. I have a class called `SubscriptionContactData`, but not `SubscriptionContactDatum`. After some days wondering what's going on I found that the problem came from the dependencies.

There are two classes related: `Subscription` and `SubscriptionContactData`. `Subscription` can has many `ContactData` and each `ContactData` belongs to 2 different `Subscriptions`: `Subs_cont_datas(id, subscription_id1, subscription_id2)`

I though the problem was there, so I tried adding a second `:belongs_to` to `ContacDatas` with no luck.

subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscription_contact_data, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

subscription_contact_data.rb

```
class SubscriptionContactData < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :subscription
end
```

**Note 1**: If I delete the `:dependent => :destroy` fon `Subscriptions.rb` the error disappears, but the DB throws a foreing key constraint error (obviously). So deleting the `:dependent` is not an option...

**Note 2**: I’m using Ruby 1.8.9, Rails 3.0.1

Comment: The "datum" sounds like Rails' pluralization is incorrectly singularizing. Maybe try inflect.uncountable %w( SubscriptionContactData ) in inflections.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, problem is not with :dependent => destroy. It is the Problem with "rails trying to pluralize the association name". So, you can try the below line.

```
has_many :subscription_contact_data, :class_name => 'SubscriptionContactData'
```

This should solve your issue.

Hope it helps.